# My date column is in following format Dec 3, 2023 · 11:32 AM UTC but i want it in DD-MM-YYYY bcoz I want to work in PowerBI and want to extract month

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I want one separate column with month name , but i am facing difficulty to convert the column. I have used power query editor for that but gives error to me.

`= Text.From(Date.Day([date])) & "-" & Text.From(Date.Month([date])) & "-" & Text.From(Date.Year([date]))`

here , date column contains values eg. Dec 3, 2023 · 11:32 AM UTC
I want seperate column of month name for each row value.

i have tried power query but didn't work.

Comment: what is the exact value in the date column? You might need to wrap it in a Date.FromText() first

Comment: values is like Dec 3, 2023 · 11:32 AM UTC actually i am scraping data from twitter so format is like that

Comment: Leaving it to Sam, seems like a reasonable answer

Answer (score 0):

It is best to ensure the column is of type Date or DateTime (and not as a string), then when loaded into the dataset, you can format it as you like.

If you were to strip out the " ·" and " UTC", then Power Query can convert it for you. As an example:

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRecords({
    [date = "Dec 3, 2023 · 11:32 AM UTC"],
    [date = "Mar 27, 2024 · 11:32 PM UTC"]
  }),
  #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Table.ReplaceValue(Source," UTC","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"date"})," ·","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"date"}),
  #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value",{{"date", type datetime}})
in
  #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: sorry but i didn't get what are u telling ? What should i change , actually i am scraping data from twitter so format is like that